# Can a dual Israel/USA citizen leave Israel without their American passport?

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, israel

I'm a native born American currently living in Israel as a citizen (dual citizenship).

Can I leave Israel to travel to Europe with only my Israeli passport, or is my US one a 'must have'?

Comment: Are you asking about legal requirements or practical considerations?

Comment: @pnuts Not relevant - Israelis are the only nationals granted visa-free access to the entire European continent. Not even EU citizens are granted that (Belarus and Russia require visas)

Answer (score 9):

To exit Israel, all you need is your Israeli passport. Israelis are uniquely granted visa-free access to all of Europe.

So if Europe's where you're going, your US passport will not be needed

Answer (score 1):

There's no requirement for you to take your US passport with you on a trip to Europe.  However, it is a good idea to do so.  For example, you might have a sudden need to travel unexpectedly to the US, such as a friend or family member falling seriously ill, and doing that will be far more complicated if you don't have your US passport with you.

Comment: I disagree. Whenever I go somewhere I always take the least amount of necessary documents, cards, and so on. Doing so, the trouble and hassle to re-do everything in case I lose my wallet/documents is minimised.

Comment: @Estey You can always keep your second passport in a different place from your first, as I usually do, to reduce the chance of losing them both at once. Having the spare can come in handy; this is one of the advantages of dual citizenship. I suppose it comes down to which of two unlikely events one thinks will be more likely to occur.